# Effect of Debrox with tubes in ears as a child?

Tags: hearing, ear

I'm on my second application of Debrox, which says "Ask a doctor before use if you have a perforation (hole) of the eardrum".  But I just now made the association, that I believe I had tubes in my ears as a child... is that a perforation of the eardrum?  Am I not supposed to use this?  If not, what could happen?

So far the stuff hasn't been effective and right now my hearing is really blocked...

Comment: Talk to your doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did go back and ask my doctor.  They said it was ok for me to use.